# Trying to create a NetSuite saved search where the result is a single row, single column containing the actual result Internal IDs

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

Let's say I create a saved search where the criteria returns 10 records.  Is there any way that what I can manipulate the results so I receive a single row, and a single column,containing an array or list of the Internal IDs of that search?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is `NS_CONCAT()`

Add a Formula(text) to your search results.  Set Summary Type to Minimum or Maximum.  Use the formula `NS_CONCAT({internalid})`.  Remove any other columns (rows in the Results tab).